# jQuery compare two sets of objects and get the location of the difference in the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a lot of questions about comparing two sets of JavaScript object on this site, but I couldn't find what I am trying to achieve.

I have two sets of objects as below.

```
var players = [
                { "id" : "45783",
                  "r3" : "DED" },
                { "id" : "54762",
                  "r3" : "DEDCCCCDDDDC" },
                { "id" : "78903",
                  "r3" : "DEDCDBDDDDDC"}
              ]
var oldPlayers = [
                { "id" : "45783",
                  "r3" : "DE" },
                { "id" : "54762",
                  "r3" : "DEDCCCCDDDD" },
                { "id" : "78903",
                  "r3" : "DEDCDBDDDDD"}
              ]
```

I want to compare the data above and find exact locations in the var players, "r3" value that's different from oldPlayers.

For example,

```
players ---- "r3" : "DED"
oldPlayers - "r3" : "DE"
```

The difference in above data is players has additional D at the character position at [2] assuming the the number starts from 0.

I have each loop that I am intending to get this location, and I am stuck how to make this work.

```
var isOldPlayers = false;

// check if oldPlayers exists
 if(oldPlayers != undefined && oldPlayers != ''){
   isOldPlayers = true;
 }

$.each(players,function(i,v){

if(isOldPlayers){
  var oldScores = oldPlayers[i]['r3'];
  var newScores = this['r3'];

   if(newScores != oldScores){
      // how can I get the exact location of the difference?
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: You could loop over the strings and see where the chars differ.

Comment: When you say "exact location" do you mean the index of the first character that isnt the same. Like given `foo` vs `foobar`, the exact location of the difference is index 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do what you need:

```js
var players = [
                { "id" : "45783",
                  "r3" : "DED" },
                { "id" : "54762",
                  "r3" : "DEDCCCCDDDDCDEWE" }, // I added chars here to show how to get the rest of the string that is different
                { "id" : "78903",
                  "r3" : "DEDCDBDDDDDC"}
              ]
var oldPlayers = [
                { "id" : "45783",
                  "r3" : "DE" },
                { "id" : "54762",
                  "r3" : "DEDCCCCDDDD" },
                { "id" : "78903",
                  "r3" : "DEDCDBDDDDD"}
              ]
$.each(players,function(index, element){
  var newR3= players[index]["r3"].split('');
  var oldR3= oldPlayers[index]["r3"].split('');
  var curId= players[index]["id"];
  
  $.each(newR3,function(i, el){
     if(el != oldR3[i]){
       $('#myDiv').append('Object '+index+' (id '+curId+') in players is different than object '+index+' (id '+curId+') in oldPlayers starting at index: '+i +'<br>');
       $('#myDiv').append('The rest of the string, from the fist difference to the end is: ' + newR3.slice(i).join('') +'<br><br>');
       
       return false;
       }


  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and providing the demo. This is what I needed.

Comment: Glad it helped, BTW , this assumes that the ids will be in the same order in both objects. If there is a chance they may not be, let me know and Ill make a modification to allow for that

Comment: I commented too soon. I also need the value in players that's different from oldPlayers. How can I get the value for the i location?

Comment: Do you want just the first letter that is different or the rest of the string from that point to the end?

Comment: glad OP found useful. As a note, `$(element).each()` is designed for DOM manipulation, whereas `$.each()` is a "generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays." http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: nice! yeah, It's an easy one to forget; make that mistake myself all too often. :P

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was able to get the letter from players by using oldR3[i].

Comment: Most likely, the new R3 will have a new character added one at a time, but if I want to get the rest of the string, how would I do that?

Comment: `newR3.slice(i).join('')` will return the the rest of the string from the point of difference to the end. Update the above to show this :)

Answer (score 2):

It may speed this up to use arrays. if the strings will contain mostly the same chars as above, this'd be a good method. would this work for you?

```
var dIdx = [v['r3'], oldPlayers[i]['r3']].sort()[0].length;

// ["DED", "DE"].sort() --> ["DE", "DED"];
// ["DE", "DED"][0] --> "DE"
// "DE".length --> 2

// "DED" differs from "DE" at index 2
```

or if you needed the difference itself, you could do:

```
var scores = [v['r3'], oldPlayers[i]['r3']].sort(),
    diff = scores[1].substr(scores[0].length);
```

## edit

**to be clear, you don't need to make the "`players`" objects arrays.**
click image for demo.

## [image]

```
var players = [
                { "id" : "45783",
                  "r3" : "DED" },
                { "id" : "54762",
                  "r3" : "DEDCCCCDDDDC" },
                { "id" : "78903",
                  "r3" : "DEDCDBDDDDDC"}
              ],
    oldPlayers = [
                { "id" : "45783",
                  "r3" : "DE" },
                { "id" : "54762",
                  "r3" : "DEDCCCCDDDD" },
                { "id" : "78903",
                  "r3" : "DEDCDBDDDDD"}
              ];
var desc = '';
$.each(players, function(i, v) {
  var dIdx = [v['r3'], oldPlayers[i]['r3']].sort()[0].length;

  desc += '<span class="h">' + v['r3'] + '</span> ' +
    'and <span class="h">' + oldPlayers[i]['r3'] + '</span> ' +
    'differ at index: <span class="hg">' + dIdx + '</span><br><br>';
});
$('body').html(desc);
```

Comment: What if the OP has `["DA", "DE"]` ?

Comment: that's why the disclaimer... I based my answer solely upon the proveided example data; if it doesn't follow that format, then this answer breaks down. In short, if the data always behaves as above, the OP would never have ["DA", "DE"];

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks simple and definitely better way to do. Unfortunately, I am not able to change the object to array.

Comment: you don't need to change your objects into arrays... sorry for ambiguity. check edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What does this .sort() do and why is it .sort()[0]?

Comment: `sort()` indexes the array's contents from smallest to largest, ie `["DEDCCCCDDDD" , "DEDCCCCDDDDC"]`, and the `[0]` grabs the value at index 0. basically we find the shortest array and take its length; this gives us the index at which difference occurs (in this case, 11). Note, this works only in a few use cases, but perfectly well for those like the example code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
$.each(players,function(iNew,vNew){
    if(isOldPlayers){               
        $.each(oldPlayers,function(iOld,vOld){
            if(vNew.id === vOld.id && vNew.r3 !== vOld.r3){
                console.log('players ----- "r3" : ' + vNew.r3 + '\noldPlayers ----- "r3" : ' + vOld.r3);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Notice that you need two inner loops, the outer one iterates over player and for each of them the inner one iterates over the oldPlayers array to look for a match.

In the inner loop you could use `this.id` and `this.r3` instead of `vOld.id` and `vOld.r3`. However, this code is not very efficient as you have to iterate over all elements of the second array for each element of the first array. If you know that all ids are unique, you could improve it further by using traditional `for` loop and break it as soon as you found an id match:

```
$.each(players,function(iNew,vNew){
    if(isOldPlayers){               
        for (var i = 0, len = oldPlayers.length ; i < len ; i += 1) {
            if(vNew.id === oldPlayers[i].id) {
                if(vNew.r3 !== oldPlayers[i].r3){
                    console.log('players ----- "r3" : ' + vNew.r3 + '\noldPlayers ----- "r3" : ' + oldPlayers[i].r3);
                }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can keep the `$.each` loop and just put `return;` after the console log in your `if(vNew.r3 !== oldPlayers[i].r3)` statement. The return will break out of the `$.each` loop  just as `break` breaks out of a standard for loop :)